# GWT FileUpload get File Full Path

Tags: gwt, file-upload

our Boss wants us to build a client only GWT App. so no server side coding will be involved in our GWT app.

Now we use a FileUpload widget to select a file from user file-system. most Browsers -for security reasons- don't allow FileUpload to return the full path of selected file. a real problem for us!

Is there a way, client-side, to fetch the filepath from a FileUpload widget?

any clever workaround or any other GWT widget that enables user file selection and returns selected file full path in file-system?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the full path of a selected file of an input element. The path will be absent or changed to avoid security risks in almost every browser browser.

You *can* get the file's name, and even its content, with the HTML5 FileAPI.

Comment: ok thanks- is HTML5 available for all new browsers versions? where can we get the HTML5 FileAPI? and what if our users have browsers that doesn't support HTML5? -thanks

Comment: Generally you can count on Chrome, Safari and Firefox. Here's a nice tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_files_from_web_applications . May I ask you why you would need the *path* of a file in a web application?

Comment: it is the descision of our boss! , our data model is stored in our GWT presenter mainely in HTML widgets-so we have our database integrated in our GWT MVP -seems weired but you know when you are forced to implement some weired requirements- our GWT is not allowed to talk to server code. everything should be done in client ! now how can we store the FileUplaod image in our Presenter model? I'm having hard time to explain this to our boss without any success!

Comment: You should tell your boss that his requirements has limits - such as handling files. You can read a user-selected file and display it, for example, if it is an image. But you cannot do anything with it's path, or open other files from a directory without the user selecting them. Good luck!

Comment: can you give a GWT snippet code how to display an image selected from FileUplaod widget ? i wonder how can we display this selected image if we don't have its full path ! -thanks much

Comment: Check the tutorial from the link of my previous comment.